# How to make a diagram of the Petersen graph using pstricks

Tags: nodes, pspicture

How do I make an equilateral star inside a pentagon?

Comment: I'd start with the pentagon, then I'd work out what an equilateral star is, and then I'd try to create the star to fit inside the pentagon. I think that would be easier than going from the inside out. [If you meant *the* Pentagon, then the answer is classified.]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility (a simple variation from [this example](http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Gallery/exa064.tex) of the PS-Tricks example gallery):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{%
 \psdots[dotscale=2](1;\INode)
 \multido{\iA=0+1}{\INode}{%
   \multido{\iB=\iA+1}{\numexpr\INode-\iA+1\relax}{% 
     \psline[linecolor=blue!50](1;\iA)(1;\iB)}}}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2,linewidth=0.2pt}
\PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different than Gonzalo's answer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node,multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \SpecialCoor
  \multido{\i=0+1}{7}{\rput{90}{\degrees[5]\pnode(1;\i){v\i}}}% Mark nodes
  \multido{\i=0+1}{5}{%
    \pcline(v\i)(v\number\numexpr\i+1)% C_5<1>
    \pcline(v\i)(v\number\numexpr\i+2)% C_5<2>
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](v\i){2pt}% node
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

There is also [`pst-poly`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-poly):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{\psdots[dotsize=0.1](1;\INode)}
  \rput{90}(2,2){\PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=5]}
  \rput{90}(2,2){\PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=5,PolyOffset=2]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```