# How to draw pentagram-like shape in Latex?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I am using latex for first time. I want to draw the picture below. How to proceed?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In the future, please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) to show what you have already tried ;-)

Comment: The first step is to start going through the TikZ manual.  You don't need to read the whole thing, but some of the tutorials will get you started.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this:

[image]

The main idea is to use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) polar coordinates and a loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=2pt}]
    \foreach \lab [count=\c, 
                   evaluate=\c as \ang using {18+72*\c}] 
    in {a,b^2, ab^2, ab, b} {
       \node[bullet] (\c) at (\ang:10mm) {};
       \node at (\ang:14mm){$\lab$};
       \foreach \i in {1,...,\c} {
          \draw(\i)--(\c);
       }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** 
Oops, I noticed that I have an extra edge. If this really is not wanted then here is a fix to give:

[image]

using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=2pt}]
    \foreach \lab [count=\c, evaluate=\c as \ang using {18+72*\c}] in {a,b^2, ab^2, ab, b} {
       \node[bullet] (\c) at (\ang:10mm) {};
       \node at (\ang:14mm){$\lab$};
    }
    \draw(5)--(1)--(2)--(3)--(4)--(5)--(3)--(1)--(4)--(2);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

## Without additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(100,100)
\put(50,100){\circle*{5}}
\put(98,65){\circle*{5}}
\put(79,10){\circle*{5}}
\put(21,10){\circle*{5}}
\put(2,65){\circle*{5}}

\put(48,105){$a$}
\put(103,65){$b$}
\put(84,10){$ab$}
\put(0,10){$ab^2$}
\put(-10,65){$b^2$}

\qbezier(79,10)(79,10)(21,10)
\qbezier(79,10)(79,10)(98,65)
\qbezier(79,10)(79,10)(50,100)
\qbezier(21,10)(21,10)(98,65)
\qbezier(21,10)(21,10)(50,100)
\qbezier(21,10)(21,10)(2,65)
\qbezier(2,65)(2,65)(50,100)
%\qbezier(2,65)(2,65)(98,65)
\qbezier(2,65)(2,65)(79,10)
\qbezier(50,100)(50,100)(98,65)

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Asymptote

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152591/189040

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
size(3cm,0);   
pair[] vertices;
int n = 5; 
real r = 1.0; 

// Add the vertices to the array:
for (real angle = 18; angle < 378; angle += 360/n) {
    // The `push` command adds its argument to the end of the array.
    vertices.push(r*dir(angle));  // r*dir(angle) gives the point with polar coordinates (r, angle).
}

// Draw the vertices:
for (pair vertex : vertices)
    dot(vertex);

// Draw a couple lines in respective:
draw(vertices[0] -- vertices[1], black);
//draw(vertices[0] -- vertices[2], black);
draw(vertices[0] -- vertices[3], black);
draw(vertices[0] -- vertices[4], black);

draw(vertices[1] -- vertices[2], black);
draw(vertices[1] -- vertices[3], black);
draw(vertices[1] -- vertices[4], black);

draw(vertices[2] -- vertices[3], black);
draw(vertices[2] -- vertices[4], black);

draw(vertices[3] -- vertices[4], black);

label("b", vertices[0], align=E);
label("a", vertices[1], align=N);
label("$b^2$", vertices[2], align=W);
label("$ab^2$", vertices[3], align=SW);
label("ab", vertices[4], align=SE);

\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## PSTricks

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228371/189040

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node,multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \multido{\i=0+1}{7}{\rput{90}{\degrees[5]\pnode(1;\i){v\i}}}% Mark nodes
  \multido{\i=0+1}{5}{%
    \pcline(v\i)(v\number\numexpr\i+1)% C_5<1>
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](v\i){2pt}% node
  }
   \multido{\i=0+1}{4}{%
       \pcline(v\i)(v\number\numexpr\i+2)% C_5<2>
   } 
   
   
\uput[90](v0){a}   
\uput[180](v1){$b^2$}  
\uput[180](v2){$ab^2$}   
\uput[0](v3){$ab$}   
\uput[0](v4){$b$}    
 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\SpecialCoor` is no longer needed.

Comment: @ArtificialOdorlessArmpit Good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Or using `shapes.geometric`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\LstG{"","a","b^2","ab^2","ab","b"}
 \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,draw,minimum width=8em] (5gon){};
 \draw (5gon.corner 2) node[circle,fill,inner
 sep=1.5pt,label={18+72*2:{\pgfmathsetmacro{\lbl}{{\LstG}[2]}$\lbl$}}]{}  
 foreach \X in {4,1,3,5} {-- (5gon.corner \X)
 node[circle,fill,inner
 sep=1.5pt,label={18+72*\X:{\pgfmathsetmacro{\lbl}{{\LstG}[\X]}$\lbl$}}]{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, this can help you.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ultra thin] (0,0)--(3.5,-2.2)--(2.7,-6)--(-2.7,-6)--(-3.5,-2.2)--(0,0)--
              (2.7,-6)--(-3.5,-2.2);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0,0)--(-2.7,-6)--(3.5,-2.2);
        \draw [fill](0,0)circle[radius=0.7mm]node[above]{$a$};
        \draw [fill](3.5,-2.2)circle[radius=0.7mm]node[right]{$b$};
        \draw [fill](2.7,-6)circle[radius=0.7mm]node[below]{$ab$};
        \draw [fill](-2.7,-6)circle[radius=0.7mm]node[below]{$ab^2$};
        \draw [fill](-3.5,-2.2)circle[radius=0.7mm]node[left]{$b^2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes. It was intentionally or deliberately made complicated to popularize the buried features in PSTricks such as:

- `\degrees`
- `saveNodeCoors`
- `\curvepnodes`
- `\psnpolygon`
- `PtoCrel`
- `DegtoAny`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\degrees[5]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=6]{0}{5}{4 t 1 4 div add PtoCrel}{A}
    \psnpolygon[showpoints,dotscale=2](0,\Anodecount){A}
    \foreach \i/\j in {0/b,1/a,2/{b^2},3/{ab^2},4/{ab}}
            {\uput{10pt}[!N-A\i.y N-A\i.x atan DegtoAny](A\i){$\j$}}
    \foreach \i/\j in {3/0,3/1,4/1,4/2}
            {\pcline(A\i)(A\j)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]